# Linear Inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't seem to get my head around on how to represent the solution region of a graph of a given linear inequality..Do I shade the true region or the false region?My textbook  says shading is done for true region but my teacher says otherwise.

Any help is greatly appreciated..
Abhijith

Comment: You can shade whatever you want, as long as you're consistent. You'll probably get credit as long as you come up with the right matrix inequality at the end.

Comment: I find it easier to shade the false region.  With several inequalities, for example six, it can be difficult to tell the difference between a region shaded six times or a region shaded only five times.  It is however rather easy to tell the difference between a region shaded zero times versus a region shaded at least one time.  It is, of course, personal preference.  There is nothing "mathematical" about shading the regions, it is only used as a convenient way to organize and display our thoughts.  So long as we can interpret what we do correctly, that is what is important.